# 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'custom navigation transition - no popping between different orientations!'

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, containment

I'm facing a problem with UIViewController containment via [MFSideMenu](https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu).

Problem is, on `ViewControllers` that support orientation, opening the side menu and selecting a different menu option (when the device is in landscape mode) causes the app to crash. This behavior worked perfectly in iOS 6, but is now failing in iOS 7.

Here's the stack trace:

```
2014-03-05 14:40:00.335 MyApp[21890:70b]
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException',
reason: 'custom navigation transition - no popping between different orientations!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x024515e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x021098b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x024513bb +[NSException raise:format:] + 139
    3   UIKit                               0x009434b4 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 988
    4   UIKit                               0x009500c7 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 688
    5   UIKit                               0x00950cb9 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 57
    6   UIKit                               0x00a8a181 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 213
    7   UIKit                               0x00880267 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    8   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0211b81f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    9   QuartzCore                          0x01ecd2ea -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    10  QuartzCore                          0x01ec10d4 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    11  QuartzCore                          0x01ec0f40 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01e28ae6 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01e29e71 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01e2a544 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x024194ce __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    16  CoreFoundation                      0x0241941f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x023f7344 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x023f6ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x023f68db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x036979e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    21  GraphicsServices                    0x03697809 GSEventRun + 104
    22  UIKit                               0x00815d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    23  MyApp                               0x000022aa main + 138
    24  libdyld.dylib                       0x02e9f701 start + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Any help in debugging this is appreciate.

P/S: Note the spelling mistake for "orientation" in the console log. I'm leaving it misspelt in case others stumble upon this problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether you are having the below functions.If then, please disable those and try,

- (BOOL) shouldAutoRotate;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation;

remove all orientation related methods.

Thanks,
ithay.